# is it possible to assign a const variable at runtime? c#

Tags: c#

I want this approach.

```
const public int x;
```

at runtime

```
x = 10; //this value will change it another Class  -->   (Not internal) 

x--> never change
```

is that possible any ways?

Comment: You could use a readonly property with a private set?

Comment: Try it and see...

Comment: If you could assign it at runtime it’s not a _constant_ anymore. I think you are looking for readonly fields which can still be set in a constructor, i.e. `readonly int x`. If you want to make it static too, i.e. only one instance for all instances of the containing class, like constants are, add the `static` modifier before `readonly`, but then you can set the value only in a static/type constructor. That being said like maccettura said you should prefer readonly properties.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cant assign value to const variable at runtime but still you can achieve your requirement logically,

You can create static readonly property, and a static constructor and assign value from the static constructor

```
public class ClassName
{
    static readonly int x;

    static ClassName()
    {
        x = 10;
    }
}
```

the compiler act as same on const property and static property, memory allocation is also same

> All constants declarations are implicitly static

ref https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/why-cant-i-use-static-and-const-together/

Comment: Though the compiler doesn’t act the same when you use them. For constants he actually copies the value to the place where the constant is referenced, whereas for readonly fields he links to the field. This is important if you ship a newer version of an assembly with an updated value. All the other assemblies referencing this assembly will still use the old value if x was a const, but the new value if x is a readonly field.

Comment: @ckuri  if you ship a newer version of an assembly than isn't the Application domain will reset?

Comment: I’m not sure if I properly understood your question, but it’s unrelated to the AppDomain. Constant values will be burned in at the call site by the compiler - it’s a compile-time issue, not a run-time issue. I’m not talking about updating an assembly when the program is still running.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using const. const should be initialized at compile time.

However, there is an alternative for this. You can use readonly which you can initialize it at runtime via constructor.

For more details, refer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596003390/ch03s25.html

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.

- const means that every instance of the member marked as const will be replaced with its value during **compilation**
- While **readonly** members will be resolved at **run-time**.